# Add a delay for IIS response

Tags: iis, iis-6, response, delay

Is it possible to force IIS to delay a response, so I want IIS to wait N seconds before sending response  back. I tried nothing as I have no idea what to try and [google didn't helped me with that](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=iis%20add%20delay%20for%20response).

Comment: Try to use `protected void Application_BeginRequest()
  {
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
  }` in MvcApplication class.

Comment: Now why would you want to do that?

Comment: @user3394380 thanks for comment, but I want configure IIS to do that.

Comment: @AgentFire I wan't to simulate slow connection to my web service hosted on IIS also I am not able to change code of that web service. And I am calling that web service not from browser so I can't use Fiddler or something

Comment: @Vladimirs you can't configure IIS for everything. Especially for something that is contrary for performance.

Comment: @AgentFire I am pretty sure that it can be handled somehow, I found http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/83d66f47-8184-4d25-afcf-c229fffdc981.mspx?mfr=true but This value must be at least 1024 Kbps. So I am looking for another approaches.

Comment: @Vladimirs You can add custom module in IIS. This module will delay request for N seconds. Your webservice will be untouched.

Comment: @user3394380 yes - custom module was what I was looking for, thanks. If you can format that as an answer I will accept that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom module in IIS. This module will delay request for N seconds. Your webservice will be untouched

Comment: This is very easy to do, there's a walk through (albeit in VB) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms227673%28v%3dvs.100%29